# Merging datetime bound dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
InstrID StartDate               EndDate                 RatingName  RatingValue
1234    2014-09-05 00:00:00.000 2016-06-26 23:59:59.000 FitchIntLT  AA+
1234    2014-09-05 00:00:00.000 2017-09-21 23:59:59.000 MoodyIntLT  Aa1
1234    2014-09-05 00:00:00.000 NULL                    SPIntLT     NR
1234    2016-06-27 00:00:00.000 NULL                    FitchIntLT  AA
1234    2017-09-22 00:00:00.000 NULL                    MoodyIntLT  Aa2
```

The table above basically updates everytime a RatingName changes.  The EndDate is populated and a new record is created with the new RatingValue.  The latest record is always the record where the EndDate is null.

I'd like to merge this dataset into the following:

```
InstrID StartDate               EndDate                 FitchIntLT   MoodyIntLT   SPIntLT 
1234    2014-09-05 00:00:00.000 2016-06-26 23:59:59.000 AA+          Aa1          NR
1234    2016-06-27 00:00:00.000 2017-09-21 23:59:59.000 AA           Aa1          NR
1234    2017-09-22 00:00:00.000 NULL                    AA           Aa2          NR
```

I was wondering what is the best way of doing this?  Or is it even possible?

Comment: yes its possible! - we'll have the query for you shortly

Comment: How does the end date of 2017-09-21 end up on the second row?

Comment: How your result would look like if `StartDate` for `SPintLt` was 2014-09-15? And are number of values in `RatingName` fixed?

Comment: Rating names are fixed.  If you wanted the SPIntLT as of 2014-09-15 then you would pick up the first record which has a start date of 2014-09-05 and end date of 2016-06-26 23:59:59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses but I managed to find a simpler solution, code is below:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare all variables and worktables
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
    instrid     INT
,   startdate   DATETIME
,   enddate     DATETIME
,   ratingname  VARCHAR(MAX)
,   ratingvalue VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #distincttemp 
(
    instrid     INT
,   startdate   DATETIME
,   enddate     DATETIME
)

INSERT #temp VALUES
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-26 23:59:59.000', 'FitchIntLT',  'AA+'),
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2017-09-21 23:59:59.000', 'MoodyIntLT',  'Aa1'),
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'SPIntLT',     'NR'),
(1234,    '2016-06-27 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'FitchIntLT',  'AA'),
(1234,    '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'MoodyIntLT',  'Aa2')

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#temp data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SELECT * FROM #temp
ORDER BY instrid, ratingname, startdate

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Distinct changes per instrument ID over time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
;;WITH CTE AS(
                SELECT 
                        a.instrid
                    ,   a.startdate

                FROM                
                (
                    SELECT 
                            instrid 
                        ,   ratingname      
                        ,   startdate   
                        ,   ISNULL(enddate,'9999-12-31 23:59:59.000') AS enddate

                    FROM #temp
                    ) AS a

                GROUP BY a.instrid, a.startdate
            )

INSERT INTO #distincttemp
    SELECT  
            CTE.instrid     
        ,   CTE.startdate   
        ,   LEAD(DATEADD(s,-1,CTE.startdate),1,null) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.instrid ORDER BY CTE.instrid, CTE.startdate) AS enddate

    FROM CTE AS CTE
    ORDER BY CTE.instrid, CTE.startdate

SELECT * FROM #distincttemp

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Flattened view
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SELECT 
        d.instrid       
    ,   d.startdate 
    ,   d.enddate
    ,   FitchIntLT.ratingvalue  AS FitchIntLT
    ,   MoodyIntLT.ratingvalue  AS MoodyIntLT
    ,   SPIntLT.ratingvalue     AS SPIntLT

FROM #distincttemp AS d

    LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS FitchIntLT
        ON FitchIntLT.instrid = d.instrid
        AND FitchIntLT.ratingname = 'FitchIntLT'
        AND (
                (
                    d.startdate BETWEEN FitchIntLT.startdate AND ISNULL(FitchIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                    AND d.enddate <= ISNULL(FitchIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                )
                OR ISNULL(d.enddate,'9999-01-01') = ISNULL(FitchIntLT.enddate,'9999-01-01')
            )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS MoodyIntLT
        ON MoodyIntLT.instrid = d.instrid
        AND MoodyIntLT.ratingname = 'MoodyIntLT'
        AND (
                (
                    d.startdate BETWEEN MoodyIntLT.startdate AND ISNULL(MoodyIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                    AND d.enddate <= ISNULL(MoodyIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                )
                OR ISNULL(d.enddate,'9999-01-01') = ISNULL(MoodyIntLT.enddate,'9999-01-01')
            )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS SPIntLT
        ON SPIntLT.instrid = d.instrid
        AND SPIntLT.ratingname = 'SPIntLT'
        AND (
                (
                    d.startdate BETWEEN SPIntLT.startdate AND ISNULL(SPIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                    AND d.enddate <= ISNULL(SPIntLT.enddate,d.enddate)
                )
                OR ISNULL(d.enddate,'9999-01-01') = ISNULL(SPIntLT.enddate,'9999-01-01')
            )

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Clean up
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #distincttemp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select InstrID, StartDate, max(EndDate) as EndDate,
       max(case when RatingName = 'FitchIntLT' then RatingValue end) as FitchIntLT,
       max(case when RatingName = 'MoodyIntLT' then RatingValue end) as MoodyIntLT,
       max(case when RatingName = 'SPIntLT' then RatingValue end) as SPIntLT
from t
group by InstrID, StartDate;
```

This doesn't produce exactly the same end dates, but this may be what you want.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't produce the dataset I require.  When there is an update to a rating value for a rating name, the current ratings values for the other rating names need to be populated as well in a new record with the update.  Hope that makes sense, I have edited my question above to provide some context as to how the first dataset works.

Answer (score 0):

OK this works please have a look:

```
create table #temp (instrid int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime, ratingname varchar(max), ratingvalue varchar(max))
insert #temp values
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-26 23:59:59.000', 'FitchIntLT',  'AA+'),
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2017-09-21 23:59:59.000', 'MoodyIntLT',  'Aa1'),
(1234,    '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'SPIntLT',     'NR'),
(1234,    '2016-06-27 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'FitchIntLT',  'AA'),
(1234,    '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', NULL                    ,'MoodyIntLT',  'Aa2')

declare @holding table (rowid int identity, instrid int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime, ratingname varchar(max), ratingvalue varchar(max)--, position int
)
insert @holding
 select * from #temp order by startdate, ratingname

declare @temp table (tempid int identity, instrid int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime,  ratingname varchar(max), ratingvalue varchar(max))
insert @temp 
 select distinct a.instrid, a.startdate, null enddate, b.ratingname, null ratingvalue  from @holding a cross join @holding b
 order by b.ratingname, a.startdate 

declare @iterator int=1, @inneriterator int=1, @instrid int, @ratingname varchar(max), @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @ratingvalue varchar(max)
while @iterator<=(Select max(rowid) from @holding)
begin
select @instrid=instrid, @ratingname=ratingname, @startdate=startdate, @enddate=isnull(enddate, @enddate), 
@ratingvalue=ratingvalue
from @holding where rowid=@iterator

while @inneriterator<=(Select max(tempid) from @temp)
begin


update @temp set ratingvalue=@ratingvalue where  tempid=@inneriterator and 
ratingname=@ratingname and startdate>=@startdate and instrid=@instrid


set @inneriterator=@inneriterator+1
end 
set @inneriterator=1
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end 


select instrid, startdate, null enddate,  max(FitchIntLT)FitchIntLT, 
 max(MoodyIntLT)MoodyIntLT, max(SPIntLT)SPIntLT into #temp2 
 from @temp pivot ( max(ratingvalue) for ratingname in ([FitchIntLT],[MoodyIntLT],[SPIntLT]))a
 group by instrid, startdate 


 select  instrid,  startdate, lead(enddate,1,null) over(order by  instrid,  startdate) enddate, FitchIntLT, MoodyIntLT, SPIntLT from (
 select  instrid,  startdate, max(enddate)enddate, FitchIntLT, MoodyIntLT, SPIntLT
 from 
 (select a.instrid, a.startdate, FitchIntLT, MoodyIntLT, SPIntLT,
 case
 when 
 (isnull(lag(FitchIntLT,1,null) over(order by a.instrid, a.startdate),'')<>FitchIntLT 
 or 
     isnull(lag(MoodyIntLT,1,null) over(order by a.instrid, a.startdate),'')<>MoodyIntLT
     or
     isnull(lag(SPIntLT,1,null) over(order by a.instrid, a.startdate),'')<>SPIntLT ) and 
 lag(a.instrid, 1,null) over (order by a.instrid, a.startdate)=a.instrid
     then dateadd(s,-1, a.startdate) end enddate
      from #temp2 a
      join @holding b on a.instrid=b.instrid and a.startdate=b.startdate)b
      group by instrid,  startdate, FitchIntLT, MoodyIntLT, SPIntLT )c
      order by instrid,  startdate

  drop table #temp 
  drop table #temp2
```